# Ingest Video stream from (RTMP/RTSP) into HDFS/HBASE

Tags: video-streaming, hdfs, apache-kafka, rtmp, flume

I want to ingest video steam file from `RTMP(real time message protocol) server into`HDFS/Hbase`.

I have read that by using Kafka & Flume this can be achieved.

I am new to Kafka & Flume. I am able to ingest data from kafka topic into HDFS by using flume agent. But I am not sure from RTMP server how can I put data into Kafka topic.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to mount the HDFS using FUSE and just use FFMPEG to ingest / write to HDFS mount point. https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS

Comment: Thanks Jony. I have not used mount HDFS using use optionbut used ffmpeg & uploaded video files into hdfs by usig hadoop fs -put.

Comment: Mounting HSFS just eliminates the whole step of uploading the video. Its up to you.

Comment: yeah Johnny you are correct. I am uploading the video into HDFS like ffmpeg -i rtmp://10.111.0.10:8080/live/cam1 -fs 10485760 -f avi - | hadoop fs -put - /tmp/spool/vid4.avi.Can you please ellaborate advantages & disadvantages of using mountable hdfs using fuse.